# Performance of gsutil cp command has declined

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have observed that the **gsutil cp** command for copying a single file to google storage was better when few such processes where running to copy different single files to different location on google storage. The normal speed at that time was ~50mbps. But as "gsutil cp" processes to copy a single file to google storage have increased, the average speed these days has dropped to ~10mbps.

I suppose "gsutil -m cp" command will not improve performace as there is only 1 file to be copied.

What can be attributed to this low speed with increase in number of gsutil cp processes to copy many single files. What can we do increase the speed of these processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gsutil can upload a single large file in parallel. It does so by uploading parts of the file as separate objects in GCS and then asking GCS to compose them together afterwards and then deleting the individual sub-objects.

N.B. Because this involves uploading objects and then almost immediately deleting them, you shouldn't do this on Nearline buckets, since there's an extra charge for deleting objects that have been recently uploaded.

You can set a file size above which gsutil will use this behavior. Try this:

```
gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=100M cp bigfile gs://your-bucket
```

More documentation on the feature is available here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#parallel-composite-uploads

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you mean the file itself is compresed, like a zip archive, or that the file is being compressed in transmission to GCS?

Comment: I mean the file is already compressed and we are copying a compressed file. Then will this approach you have suggested will work or not?

Comment: I see no reason why it wouldn't work because the file is compressed.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime Google released the [`gcloud storage`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage) CLI which automatically optimizes the parallelization of uploads and downloads; no additional parameters required! For many situations the performance it delivers will cause you to reach some other bottheleck (network, host cpu, etc) and it beats `gsutil` for performance and ease of use every time. For copying a file with it see the docs for [`gcloud storage cp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/storage/cp).

As mentioned in another answer, `gsutil cp` and also `gcloud storage cp`, perform uploads using the Composite upload pattern which means they break a large file into chunks, upload the chunk files, combine them, and delete the chunks. Because the temporary chunk files are normal files in the bucket if saved as Nearline when you delete them you'll be charged an early delete fee. The two CLI tools I mentioned will automatically disable composite uploads if it detects an interoperability issue.

Another option if you can code it yourself is to use the [Multipart Upload (MPU) API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/multipart-uploads) as it does not suffer from these same interoperability challenges. I discuss this in much more detail in my recent blog post
[High throughput file transfers with Google Cloud Storage (GCS)](https://www.beginswithdata.com/2024/02/01/google-cloud-storage-max-throughput/).